# Is it possible to make a date datatype accept 13 as a month and 30 for all months?

Tags: .net, calendar, culture

I am in Ethiopia and we have 13 months. 12 of them with 30 days each and 13th month with 5 or 6 days. I want to sort my data by date using the `BindingSource` sort method. But to do that, I need to set my date field a date data type. When I set the `DataType` to date, I can't enter some values like 13 for the month value and 30 for day value of 2nd month.

What I want is just to make my application accept 13 as a month and 30 as a day for all months, so that I can sort my data by date. Is it possible to do so by setting culture for my application or by some other means?

Comment: what language/framework are you using?  (ex. VB.Net, Java etc.)

Comment: What, exactly, is stopping you from entering a 13?  Is it the database or some other code?

Comment: i set the database field to string and it is okay! But i set the datatable's field to date on the dataset designer. It says could not store 13062000 in date column at 
 Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database2DataSet.Table1)

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you could load up the `CultureInfo` corresponding to language/country for Ethiopia. It appears that the native language in [Ethiopia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopia) is [Amharic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amharic) which has ISO 639 short code of "am" and the ISO 3166 country code for Ethiopia is "ET". Thus, it appears that the correct [culture code](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/globalization/demos/CultureInfo.aspx) for Ethiopia is "am-ET". Thus, try the following.

```
CultureInfo ethiopia = new CultureInfo("am-ET");
int year = 2002; // it is currently 2002 in Ethiopia
int months = ethiopia.Calendar.GetMonthsInYear(year);
for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(ethiopia.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, i));
}
```

And then, [as it is the 13th month that has five or days](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_calendar)

```
DateTime time = new DateTime(2002, 13, 5, ethiopia.Calendar);
```

would be legal.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you could also look at how to create a custom calendar using this [CodeProject on the Vietnamese Lunar Calendar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/VnCalendar.aspx) as an example.

Comment: The Ethiopic numbering system is fascinating as it does not have a zero: http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2005/02/01/364376.aspx

Comment: How can I do this to change the datatable? I mean it is the datatable that's not accepting the data coming from the database.

Comment: Try setting the `DataTable.Locale` property to an instance of `CultureInfo` that represents the "am-ET" culture. I don't know that will work, but it's the first thing to try. The problem is that the `DataTable` will still use the `InvariantCulture` for a vast majority of its functionality.

Comment: setting the locale of the datatable changes nothing. also "am-ET" is not a valid culture name. it seems that ethiopia is not in the caltureinfo culture list. can you show me how to create a custom calendar, the link you gave me is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I used this as a solution.

you could add a separate column in your datatable to account for the extra epagomenal days... then sort your data by both columns. for instance: here would be a sample table sorted descending first by Column1 then by Column2:

RegDate----------------EpaDate

12/30/09--------------- 1/5/2010
12/30/09----------------1/4/2010
12/30/09----------------1/3/2010
12/30/09----------------1/2/2010
12/30/09----------------1/1/2010
12/30/09------------------NULL
12/29/09------------------NULL
12/28/09------------------NULL